# Include library project to android appcelerator titanium module

Tags: android, module, titanium, appcelerator, library-project

I have an android library project, which I want to include to my titanium android module. In the documentation I found no way to reference the library project. For adding a third party library the documentation has a guide to include a *.jar* file. So I tried to add the *.jar* file. 
The library project also depends on native libraries (*.so* files) and resources. I experimented a little bit and I got it somehow working, that the ressources and native libraries are included in my *.apk*. The problem is: at runtime I get a `ClassDefNotFoundError`. 
I tried pretty much everything and I don't know how to get this running. 
BTW I'm a newbie, so maybe it is not even possible what I'm trying to do. 
Can anyone please help?

Comment: edit your question and add images and code where-ever *necessary*

Comment: somone at least know if it is possible to include an android library project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/176936/android-module-how-to-inclue-an-android-library-that-requres-r-file)
fixed it. Just modify the script.